# could not convert to integer . Path ' exitCode'. value too big or too small for Int32. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

My program works fine but when it finished gives error like that :

could not convert to integer . Path ' exitCode'. value too big or too small for Int32

Python 3.7

```
from re import compile
from os import path, walk
from pywinauto import win32api
from easygui import fileopenbox
from pyautogui import confirm, alert
from sys import exit


def Find_Client_Path():
    file_name = compile("LeagueClient.exe")
    for driver in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split("\000")[:-1]:
        for root, folders, files in walk(driver):
            for file in files:
                find_file = file_name.search(file)
                if find_file:
                    return path.join(root, file)
    return Find_Path_Manually()


def Find_Path_Manually():
    alert(
        "Please select LeagueClient.exe in Riot Games / League of Legends /.",
        title="Warning",
        button="Okay",
    )
    path = fileopenbox()
    if path.find("LeagueClient.exe") != -1:
        return path
    else:
        secim = confirm(
            "You choose the worng file. Please select LeagueClient.exe in Riot Games / League of Legends / . If you want to close bot click EXIT button.",
            title="UYARI!",
            buttons=("OKAY", "EXIT"),
        )
        if secim == "EXIT":
            sys.exit()
        elif secim == "OKAY":
            return Find_Path_Manually()
```

Comment: Could we see some code?

Comment: i just added the code

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the full stack trace so we could see which line is generating the error.